# Any way to force output file name in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a yaml option to set the output name in Rmarkdown? I know this is possible with book down, but I want to use it for individual documents.

Comment: Create your .Rmd document, and then create a separate R script in which you use `rmarkdown::render()` to render that .Rmd document. It's in that function that you can specify the name of your output file.

Comment: thanks for this.. I actually did know about render but was hoping there might be a hidden option in the yaml. perhaps not...